# Как правильно подключить шрифт?

Tags: css, шрифты

Есть набор шрифтов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подключаю их таким образом:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PF Highway Sans Pro';
    src:
    local('PF Highway Sans Pro'),
    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

вроде бы все правильно, вопрос только с локальным файлом.
как назвать его? на компьютере он называется **"полужирный"**

шрифт на компьютере сгруппирован:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если открыть: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

может быть независимо от названия шрифта нужно обращаться к самой группе?

Comment: Обращайтесь к группе, если нужен жирный, поставьте font-weight: 700 или 900

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так подключить

```
@font-face{

    font-family: 'PF Highway Sans Pro';

    src: url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.eot');

    src: url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.eot?iefix') format('eot'),

    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'),

    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),

    url('../fonts/PFHighwaySansPro-Bold.svg#webfont') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;

    font-style: normal;

    }
```

А затем в css напишите жирность текста, такую которую вам необходимо

***font-weight: 600;***

Comment: А о том как правильно подписать жирный шрифт, то... как хотите так и пишите. К примеру   PF Highway Sans Pro Bold - Жирный,  PF Highway Sans Pro Light - Тонкий...

Comment: у вас не определен в стилях локальный шрифт, а я хочу чтобы использовался он при его наличии на компьютере

Comment: Я бы вам не советовал так подключать, подключите через GOOGLE FONTS (там есть все шрифты)